# Setting default value for integer field in django models

Tags: python, django, integer, django-models

I'm trying to set a default value for the integer field in Django model using

```
models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default='0')
```

Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [default value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default) in your example is set to string (`'0'`), but it should be integer. Try this instead:

```
models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```